# Partial sorting of a vector

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of random numbers, I can order them lowest to highest:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(20)
v <- x[order(x)]
```

Now, say I want to order them but with some degree of noise.

I can randomly move elements like this:

```
z <-sample(1:20,2)
replace(v, z, v[rev(z)])
```

but this doesn't necessarily move closely related values. I could be equally likely to randomly switch the 1st and 20th values as the 5th and 6th. I would like to have some control over the switching, so I can switch more closely related values.

Ideally, I would be able to reorder the vector to have a specific Spearman's correlation. Say rather than the Spearman correlation of rank order being 1 when they are perfectly ordered, is there a way to reorder that same vector of numbers to have e.g. a Spearman's correlation of 0.5 ?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work in many situations - but not in cases where I already have the vector of numbers and wish to put them in an order of certain correlation. These questions generate new data.

Comment: Ah - sorry, typed too fast.  Here, I am after a Spearman's correlation.   So, a Spearman's correlation of 1 would mean that all `n` values are in exact ascending order. I wish to reorder those exact values such that they could be put into a specific order corresponding to a defined Spearman's correlation.

Comment: Do you specifically care about switching similar values or do you only care about getting a desired correlation?

Comment: I'm not too beholden to the desired correlation.  I essentially want to just add some amount of desired noise to the ordering, and I thought going after a specific correlation might be one way to achieve it.  Switching similar values seemed another logical approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you added some noise to their rankings. This will makes sure values don't get moved too far away from the starting point. For example

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 50
D <- 3 # controls how far things can move
x <- runif(N)
v <- x[vx <- order(rank(x) + runif(N, -D, D))]
z <- x[order(x)]

layout(matrix(c(1,3,2,3), nrow=2))
plot(v, main ="Ordered")
plot(z, main ="Mixed")
plot(v, z, xlab="ordered", ylab="mixed"); abline(0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer. Just a small remark: if you use `rnorm()`, instead of `runif()` to modify the ranks, you will be able to have any two value potentially swap, with nearest values to be most likely. You will have to set a `SD` for `rnorm()`, just like you set a `D` for `runif()`, but in that case it will be a measure of 'flexibility', instead of 'boundaries'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I have completely understood your question but here's a start. I am simply recursively swapping random consecutive values of the sorted vector. You can control the amount of swapping with `n_swaps` argument.  -

```
noisy_sort <- function(x, n_swaps) {
  sorted_x <- sort(x)
  indices <- sample(seq_along(x[-1]), n_swaps)
  for(i in indices) {
    sorted_x[c(i, i+1)] <- sorted_x[c(i+1, i)]
  }
  sorted_x
}

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(20) 

result <- noisy_sort(x, 3)

order(result)
[1]  1  2  3  5  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 13 12 14 15 16 17 19 18 20
              ^  ^                    ^  ^              ^  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very rudimentary algo.

Using [Spearman correlation for distinct ranks](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b69578f3203ecf1b85b1a0929772b376ae07a3ce), you can back out the desired sum of squared difference (SSE) between ranks. Then, using a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) approach, you sample a pair of indices to swap and transit to the new vector with swapped elements if it improves the SSE towards desired score.

I used the number of iterations as the stopping criteria. You can change the condition so that it meets a target tolerance level.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 20
x <- runif(n)
v <- sort(x)

calc_exp_sse <- function(rho, N) {
    (1 - rho) * N * (N^2 - 1) / 6
}
exp_sse <- calc_exp_sse(0.5, n)

ord <- 1:n
vec <- ord
for (i in 1:1000) {
    swap <- vec
    swid <- sample(n, 2L)   
    swap[swid] <- swap[c(swid[2L], swid[1L])]
    if (abs(exp_sse - sum((ord-swap)^2)) < abs(exp_sse - sum((ord-vec)^2))) {
        vec <- swap
    }
}
vec
cor(vec, ord, method="spearman")
#[1] 0.5007519

cor(v, v[vec],  method="spearman")
#[1] 0.5007519
```

Comment: Nice idea! (aaaand the minimum characters for SO)